# svcutil cannot see multiple actions of the same operation

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, .net-core, soap, svcutil.exe

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and I am trying to add a wcf service reference to the solution. The problem is that there may be more than one action in the same operation in the soap service reference I am trying to add, but svcutil only produces the Reference code for one of these actions. How can I solve this situation?

There are 2 actions in the operation named WorkingType but svcutil only generates methods for the first action.

```
POST /nnn.web/nnnWS.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: nnn.example.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/WorkingType"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthenticationHeader xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Username>string</Username>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </AuthenticationHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <WorkingType xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <UpdatedDate>dateTime</UpdatedDate>
    </WorkingType>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <WorkingTypeResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <WorkingTypeResult>
        <WorkingType>
          <WorkingTypeId>int</WorkingTypeId>
          <WorkingTypeName>string</WorkingTypeName>
        </WorkingType>
        <WorkingType>
          <WorkingTypeId>int</WorkingTypeId>
          <WorkingTypeName>string</WorkingTypeName>
        </WorkingType>
      </WorkingTypeResult>
    </WorkingTypeResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: It is difficult for svcutil to interfere with the process of generating code. You can try changing the name of the operation with the same name.